# modify ssh_config ip addresses based on current ip

Tags: ssh, bashrc

I'd like to be able to modify ssh_config aliases based on my current IP address.

I have a laptop which I carry around from network to network, and a camera which I do the same with. I have setup the dhcp on these networks to always give the camera the same IP address, and I calculate what it should be in my bashrc and put the camera IP into an environment variable.

Is there any way to do something like the following inside ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host camera
    HostName $CAMERA_IP
    User camuser
```

The above doesn't work as ssh complains:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname $CAMERA_IP: Name or service not known
```

Comment: you could just add an alias in your hosts file ... instead of the ssh_config

Comment: But I want to do it based on my IP. I don't think the hosts file is aware of my user's environment either is it?

Comment: you can just alias it.      add an entry like IP camera

Comment: Yeah, but if I get the ssh alias's to work I get scp and rsync aliases all too.

Comment: it'll all work if you just reference camera

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want to create aliases like sshcamera and scpcamera to work around modifying ~/.ssh/config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing calculation in your bashrc, you can also generate the ssh_config you need from a template using sed.

The template (.ssh/ssh_config_t):

```
Host camera
    Hostname IP_PH
    user camuser
```

The script in bashrc

```
sed -e "s/IP_PH/$CAMERA_IP/" ~/.ssh/ssh_config_t > ~/.ssh/ssh_config
```

Comment: +1 41 seconds faster than me :)

Comment: That's a good idea. I can even edit the ~/.ssh/config directly with sed since I know what the IP addresses that I set are.

Answer (score 0):

I think how I would solve this would be to use a template config file as follows.

**~/.ssh/config_template**:

```
Host camera
    HostName $CAMERA_IP
    User camuser
```

And then a simple update script.

**~/.ssh/update_config.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do whatever to set $CAMERA_IP
CAMERA_IP=192.168.1.1

# Update config file
sed "s/\$CAMERA_IP/$CAMERA_IP/" ~/.ssh/config_template > ~/.ssh/config
```

And then just call `~/.ssh/update_config.sh` from your `bashrc` file. Just remember to not make any manual changes to `ssh_config`.